# Play framework: empty body in post request

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

Helo! I have a following code:

```
def foo = Action { request =>
    Ok(request.body.asText.getOrElse("no body"))
}
```

In frontend have a form like this:

```
<form action="@controllers.routes.Application.foo()" method="POST">
    <input name="name" type="text">
    <input name="surname" type="text">
     <button type="submit">
</form>
```

If I fill the form and click submit, they gives me result: no body.
But if I add brakepoint in debugger to Ok(..), they shows me, that body is not emty.

```
AnyContentAsFormUrlEncoded(Map(name -> ArrayBuffer(123), surname -> ArrayBuffer(123)))
```

Why, that doesn't give me body as text, or as anything else, and how I can get them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your form and your debugging output, you should be using `asFormUrlEncoded`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need the following as well:

```
<form ... enctype="text/plain">
```

to specify that the payload is plain text. Then the `.asText` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your content type probably is something other than `text/plain`. The `BodyParser` will only return a result, when the content type is the expected.

edit: Instead of `asText` try `asRaw`.

Comment: Did this thing: Ok(request.body.asRaw.get.toString()), and that gives me an error: NoSuchElementException: None.get

Comment: Even though the body is non-empty? That's strange.